# How to clear local storage before running each test in WebdriverIO?

Tags: webdriver, automated-tests, cypress, webdriver-io

I am writing tests for a React based web tool. So I want to clear all local storage such as login information etc. before each test. I have majorly worked in Cypress, where this was just a simple command.

```js
cy.clearLocalStorage();
```

I am now using WebdriverIO and this is the approach that I was trying out (in the test file).

```js
afterEach(() => {
    browser.executeScript('window.localStorage().clear()');
});
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working. Moreover, I would prefer a global solution, something that I don't have to write in each test. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

From the [WebdriverIO Docs](http://v4.webdriver.io/v3.4/api/protocol/localStorage.html):

```
// remove the storage item for the given key
client.localStorage('DELETE', 'someKey');

// clear the storage
client.localStorage('DELETE');
```

You can clear localStorage by running this preset function.

Comment: it says 'client is not defined'.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost right in your assumption. I'd suggest using official docs to eliminate minor errors.

Instead of `executeScript` use https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/execute.html

`localStorage` is not a function, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

So it should be

```js
afterEach(() => {
    browser.execute('window.localStorage.clear()');
});
```

P.S.
Assuming you are using WebdriverIO 5 or above.

Comment: This did not work, I wanted to clear out the local storage so that the login page appears again after each hook, that did not happen.

Comment: "Something doesn't work" comment is not really helpful. Please be more specific

Answer (score 0):

So, after a lot of time, we realized the problem.
The `cy.clearLocalStorage()` cleans only the local storage under the `baseUrl` definition.

If you would like to open multiple pages, you have to explicit define the clearing in the `cy.visit()` call, like that:

```js
    cy.visit(`subdomain.another.domain`, {
      onBeforeLoad(win) {
        win.localStorage.clear();
      },
    });
```

In this case, the local storage for the exact domain, will be deleted.

I hope, this workaround helps.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need to do in Wdio to replicate the **cy.clearLocalStorage()**
is the following

**// Async**

```
await browser.reloadSession()
```

**// Sync**

```
browser.reloadSession()
```

For example, could be applied like this to log back in again without the cache stored by the previous session:

```
      beforeEach( async function () {
        if(this.currentTest._currentRetry != 0) {
            await browser.reloadSession()
        }
      }
```

Or use it to test a returning user:

```
    //Get URL before abandoning the flow 
    const currentURL = await browser.getUrl()
    
    //Clear local storage application
    await browser.reloadSession()
    
    //Navigate back to the flow
    await browser.navigateTo(currentURL)

    //Authenticate from the page the user left
    await basePage.authenticateMethod(user)
```